# How to publish _IntrinsicData database in LightSwitch?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

My Lightsitch app works great in my dev computer. However, when I publish it, it gives errors because the _IntrinsicData database does not exist in the server.
I thought that this database is automatically created but probably not.

So, I created a database in the server, then I executed aspnet_regsql to create the membership tables.

Now, the app gives me another error: Invalid object name 'RolePermissions'.
This table does not form part of Membership, it is a specific to LightSwitch.

Obviously I am doing something wrong because I should not create manually the tables.

How can I publish a LS project?

By the way, it does not happen if I select "No auth"  or "Any Windows User" options when I publish. It is normal because then LS does not need the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found a workaround. It seems that publishing directly does not create the database. So, I published it via package, and then I extract the sql script from this package. Finally I executed the script in the server and everything works.

Comment: Publishing directly definitely should have created the intrinsic database (as long as "Publish database schema" was checked on the "Data Connections" page of the publish wizard).  Certain versions of LightSwitch had a bug where the database wouldn't be published if there were no tables defined in the intrinsic data source (even though none should need to be defined if you are just using the database for User/Role tables)